# Which file should we upload in the Apps for SharePoint library?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have developed a SharePoint hosted app and also created an App catalog site. But I'm not sure which file of my SharePoint hosted app should I upload in to Apps for SharePoint document library. Can someone please clarify me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to package the app, which will create a file ending with a .app extension. That is what you add to the app catalog.

Comment: Thanks a lots for answering...can you also tell me how do I add this App from the Apps for SharePoint document library in to my site?

Comment: @user318197 go to the site where you want to install the app, click the gear icon, then click Add an App. From there, click on the icon for the app you added to the catalog and follow the prompts to install it.